# Qt5 fullscreen resize issue

Tags: fullscreen, qt5, ubuntu-14.04, tablet-pc

I have an issue with the fullscreen state of my QMainWindow (I use QT 5.3.1).

It works perfectly well with Windows and Debian on a PC, but when I try it on a tablet PC (C22 Tablet PC, Ekoore) with Ubuntu 14.04, the behavior is different.

As you can see on the below screenshot, the task bar and the window border are hidden, but it seams that the window is not resized to take all the screen...

http://postimg.org/image/ouyb1fvz5/

I confirmed that by printing debug in the resizeEvent method. Nothing happen when I call showFullscreen().

What is wrong here ? Have you any ideas ? I cannot find anything about that problem.

Thanks in advance. Cedric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. My window was too big and a part was out of the screen before the call to showFullscreen().
It seams that the resize does not work in this case.

After resizing my window in Qt Creator, the fullscreen now works fine. I do not have a better answer about why it does not work on ubuntu when the window is too big.